# HTML If class paragraph contains string do

Tags: html, shopify, liquid

I am trying to edit code using Shopify and their Liquid templates. It should be simple and I've searched their site and online. Their suggestions have not provided me a solution.
This is the original line of code:

```
{% if settings.display_quickview_vendor %}
  <p class="product-vendor"><label>Vendor</label><span></span></p>
{% endif %}
```

This statement will always be true, referencing the json file. Using the class="product-vendor" and the .js file, it inserts the vendor name with the Vendor label from product setup.

My goal is that when my vendor name is set to "--" (using a drop down in product setup) the vendor line of code will not be executed.

I've tried this

```
{% if settings.display_quickview_vendor %}
    {% if product-vendor != "--" %}
        <p class="product-vendor"><label>Vendor</label><span></span></p>
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

I've also replace the second if statement with the following.

```
{% if product.vendor != "--" %}
{% if product.vendor contains '--' %}
{% if product-vendor contains '--' %}
```

My experience is with C# and VBA. I have a feeling that I'm not fully understanding what it is that I need to be asking or searching for.

This is the .js file where the quickview window is called.

```
        initQuickView: function() {
        e(".quickview-button a").click(function() {
            var i = e(this).attr("id");
            return Shopify.getProduct(i, function(i) {
                var a = e("#quickview-template").html();
                e(".quick-view").html(a);
                var o = e(".quick-view");
                if (o.find(".product-title a").text(i.title), o.find(".product-title a").attr("href", i.url), o.find(".product-vendor span").length > 0 && o.find(".product-vendor span").text(i.vendor), o.find(".product-type span").length > 0 && o.find(".product-type span").text(i.type), o.find(".product-inventory span").length > 0) {
                    var n = i.variants[0].inventory_quantity;
                    o.find(".product-inventory span").text(n > 0 ? null != i.variants[0].inventory_management ? n + " in stock" : "Many in stock" : "Out of stock")
                }
```

This is from the schema.json file.

```
  {
    "type": "checkbox",
    "id": "display_quickview_vendor",
    "label": "Display Vendor?",
    "default": true
  },
```

This is from the data.json file.

```
"display_quickview_vendor": true,
```

Comment: Have you tried just echo'ing out `product.vendor` to see what it looks like?

Comment: If `{% if settings.display_quickview_vendor %}` is always true, then just remove it and use the one condition you need to make the code changes you want. I also agree with @AlexanderWigmore that if you are using product-vendor then you should print it out to see what it looks like.

Comment: I tried this and it returned nothing.          <? php echo product.vendor; ?>

Comment: Does product exist? What about `{% dd(settings) %}`?

Comment: If I leave the code the way it is, it will work. It show's as "Vendor     --". It just looks bad to us. I will continue to try new things to figure this out. I'm just a little daunted. There is html, .js, php, .css, .json and it seems the list goes on.

Comment: using {% dd(settings) %} gives this error: Liquid syntax error: Unknown tag 'dd'. I'm trying to look for a similar command on the Shopify developer page.

Comment: I suspect this is something you will need to change in the javascript file, not the liquid template. Can you find the code snippet where it appends the vendor name?